# Cypher LOAD FROM CSV performance for relationship merge

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am merging large batches of ~500,000 relationships with the `LOAD CSV` command:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'http://file.csv'
MATCH (a:Label {uid: csv.uid1}),(b:Otherlabel {uid: csv.uid2})
MERGE (a)-[:TYPE {key1: csv.key1}]->(b)
```

Both `uid` properties have a `UNIQUE` constraint.

The CSV file looks like:

```
uid1,uid2,key1
123,abc,some_value
456,def,some_value
```

This is usually **very** fast (< 1 min) when there are many different nodes on each side.

But performance drops dramatically when I load batches where a single `a` node is connected to many different `b` nodes. The `uid1` is always the same but schema constraints are still there. ~30,000 relationships take ~8 min to load.

Am I missing something here? What could explain the huge performance difference in `MERGE`ing 'many-to-many' relationships vs. 'one-to-many'?

Comment: What does your indexing look like?

Comment: I just verified this behavior with a ~300,000 line CSV file that I created with unique random values for uid1 and uid2. I wonder if it has to do with having to resize the relationships list for the 'a' node when a single 'a' node has many relationships created between it and other nodes? When no single node gets a large number of relationships, each relationship list stays small.

Comment: There are unique constraints on 'uid' for both labels. @JimBiard I assume something like this happens, maybe something goes to filesystem when adding many relationships. `CREATE` statements are still very fast though, did you try that as well?

Comment: That pretty much proves what is going on. See the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment on the question, I verified this behavior with a ~300,000 line CSV file that I created with unique random values for uid1 and uid2. @MartinPreusse then mentioned that if you change the query to use CREATE instead of MERGE, the query is fast. This observation made me realize what is going on.

The slowdown is caused by the need to scan the relationships list of the 'a' node each time a MERGE is performed. When a CREATE is performed, the relationship is added without testing first to see if the relationship already exists. When the relationship lists remain short (first case), scanning the relationship lists has little impact. When the relationship lists are growing long (second case), the repeated scanning of a growing list is dominating the process. In my test I linked all 300,000 nodes to a single node using a MERGE clause and it took hours.

If you don't have to worry about creating duplicate relationships, you can use CREATE without fear. Even if duplicates are an issue, it might be faster to use CREATE and then craft a query that will remove the duplicates.

Comment: Makes sense, complexity is high if neo scans the complete growing list. I switched to `CREATE` and handle duplicates on the application level. Maybe the question is helpful for somebody stumbling over this issue.